# A book about a boy with special powers in a school with others like him

Tags: story-identification, powers, psychic

I think it was about a boy that wound up in a school with other kids that had powers. I think the story was told from his point of view. Each child was different. One could read minds, a girl could heal people, etc. I think they were held captive. I believe to be trained into a weapon they escaped. I believe wound up taking a car and driving up through California towards Oregon looking for a certain place, they wind up fighting the ones who held them captive.

I read it mid to late 90s and some suggest James Patterson's *The Lake House* but it wasn't about kids who could fly so that isn't it.

Comment: Any of [this lot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_Mountain) look like it?

Comment: It sounds similar to Welcome to the Ark, by [Stephanie Tolan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephanie_S._Tolan) but not 100%

Comment: We may never hear from the the querent, but I have "Welcome to the Ark" on request from the library.

Comment: "Welcome to the Ark" looks unlikely. The book is from the perspective of the four children in a sort of alternating fashion, and their abilities are more about telepathy and empathy with shades of being able to directly manipulate "violence" in others.